set the font size of a child element relative to the height of its parent box when the parent box doesn't have a specified font size
I need to dynamically set the font size of the <span> element relative to the  10% height of the div.
HTML:
<div>
  <span>Example text</span>
</div>

CSS:
div {
  height: 20vh;
  width: 100vh;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  position: relative;
}

I tried using vh, vmin, rem, em, % units with no luck.
Is there a way to achieve this with pure CSS? Without relying on JavaScript?

Use Container Queries/Units

Container queries enable you to apply styles to an element based on the size of the element's container. If, for example, a container has less space available in the surrounding context, you can hide certain elements or use smaller fonts.


The container query length units are:

cqw: 1% of a query container's width
cqh: 1% of a query container's height
cqi: 1% of a query container's inline size
cqb: 1% of a query container's block size
cqmin: The smaller value of either cqi or cqb
cqmax: The larger value of either cqi or cqb




div {
  height: 30vh;
  width: 100vh;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  container-type: size;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

span {
  font-size: 10cqh;
}

.big {
  font-size: 20cqh;
}
<div>
  <span>Example text</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="big">Example text</span>
</div>




Thank you so much for your solution, exactly what I was looking for. But, can you please explain why is the height of the font exceeds the total height of the container when using font-size: 100cqh? Screenshot: https://prnt.sc/a61U6Ktvi4YX (is that because of the font file itself?)

...that plus line-height and the ascenders and descenders of the font glyphs.
